# python printing CQL output in native format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've python program which is trying to connect to apache cassandra using python-cassandra driver and execute some queries. The resultset I'm getting back is either a list or a dictionary. However, I want the output to be printed back to the user in the native cql output format (as columns and rows)

like this,

```
 keyspace | durable_writes | name    | strategy_class | strategy_options
----------+----------------+---------+----------------+---------------------    -------
  history |           True | history | SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"1"}
  ks_info |           True | ks_info | SimpleStrategy |{"replication_factor":"1"}

(2 rows)
```

is there a module I can use to achieve this ? I use the following code to test

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import dict_factory

def fireCql(cqlStatement):

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
        username='myusername', password='myPassWord')
cluster = Cluster(['cassandra.myhostname.com'],auth_provider=auth_provider)

session = cluster.connect('my_keyspace')
session.row_factory = dict_factory

rows = session.execute(cqlStatement)

return rows
```

Python:2.7

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a feature within the python driver itself. If you think a lot of people would want this, you could request it to the python driver group.

However here is the code that Cassandra uses to generate that formatting. You could use that as a base to implement the logic to parse your result and format as you want.

From https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b02dec3da539d181544cfb0288102d6073f36264/bin/cqlsh.py

```
def print_formatted_result(self, formatted_names, formatted_values):
    # determine column widths
    widths = [n.displaywidth for n in formatted_names]
    if formatted_values is not None:
        for fmtrow in formatted_values:
            for num, col in enumerate(fmtrow):
                widths[num] = max(widths[num], col.displaywidth)

    # print header
    header = ' | '.join(hdr.ljust(w, color=self.color) for (hdr, w) in zip(formatted_names, widths))
    self.writeresult(' ' + header.rstrip())
    self.writeresult('-%s-' % '-+-'.join('-' * w for w in widths))

    # stop if there are no rows
    if formatted_values is None:
        self.writeresult("")
        return

    # print row data
    for row in formatted_values:
        line = ' | '.join(col.rjust(w, color=self.color) for (col, w) in zip(row, widths))
        self.writeresult(' ' + line)

    self.writeresult("")
```